# Removing PIN in Core Bluetooth Connection

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on an application that connects phones via core bluetooth (BLE). The connection and data transmission work beautifully, but there is one small imperfection. When connecting to a new device, a pin must be entered on one of the devices. The application is supposed to be very instantaneous, and the pin-input greatly interrupts this process. I'm not worried about security, and I've personally connected my phone to many bluetooth devices without entering pins, so I was just wondering how this could be done with the iOS api.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify any of your peripheral's characteristics with an 'encryptionRequired' property (`CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired` or `CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicateEncryptionRequired`) or permissions (`CBAttributePermissionsReadEncryptionRequired` or `CBAttributePermissionsWriteEncryptionRequired`) then bonding is required between the devices.

If the devices aren't already bonded then this will trigger the pairing dialog and require a pin to be entered.  If you don't specify any of the encryption properties or permissions on your peripheral's characteristics then you won't be prompted to pair.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Paulw11. For my peripheral characteristic, I'm using CBCharacteristicProperties.Read for my property and CBAttributePermissions.Readable as my permission. If I set both (or just the properties) to nil then I get an error: "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Characteristics with cached values must be read-only.'" Can there potentially be something else in my code requiring encryption?