# Objective-c iOS BLE write value with encryption

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, bluetooth

I am currently working on an application that acts as BLE Central to communicate with Bluetooth peripheral device. I am trying to write value to Peripheral with encryption so it cannot be sniffed by others.

I have declared services and characteristic as NSArray.

```
    myservices = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1stServiceUUID"], [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2ndServiceUUID"]];

mycharacterstics = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1sCharacteristicUUID"], [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2ndCharacteristicUUID"]];
```

When app found matching service nearby, app connects it and write value right away from didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService

```
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:mycharacterstics[0]]) {
        _discoveredPeripheralCharactersticsNotify = characteristic;

        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }

    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:mycharacterstics[1]]) {
        _discoveredPeripheralCharactersticsWrite = characteristic;

        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }

    [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:testData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
}
```

**Expected Result:**

App writes encrypted value to peripheral in both foreground and background.

**Actual Result:**

App in foreground: app displays pair request popup either user wants to "Pair" or "Cancel". If selected "Pair", value is encrypted so it cannot be sniffed. If selected "Cancel", writes value still that is NOT encrypted so it can be sniffed.

App in background: app does not display pair request. Just writes value to peripheral as soon as connected without encryption.

**Other behaviour:**

iOS 10 and lower: app writes encrypted value all the time even user selects "Cancel" from pair request popup if app is in foreground and randomly app writes encrypted value or not if app is in background.

I do not understand why the app behave differently in different OS version.

**Questions:**

Can I make the app always write value with encryption or if user selects "Cancel" from pair request popup then app does not write value?

How can I control pair request popup depends on user's selection?

How can I control pairing when app in background?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Regards.

Comment: If you have control on the device firmware, force a pairing. So set the property of the characteristic as such, and when the iPhone wants to read/write, it have to pair. It can't cancel it.

Comment: @Larme do you mean control on peripheral side?

Comment: Yes. See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097414/removing-pin-in-core-bluetooth-connection If you put theses property, you have to pair. And a after a cancel, you shouldn't be able to write.

Comment: @Larme Awesome I will try that, what will happen if app is in background? I have not seen any pairing request popup in background. Do I have to bring an app in foreground and write value?

Comment: If the app is in the background then no pairing dialog will be displayed, as it would be confusing to the user to suddenly see a pairing dialog. Pairing only happens once and you would normallly do this in your app where the user goes through a device discovery and pairing process.

Comment: Once it’s paired, it’s paired. To remove the pairing you have to go to Settings.app/Bluetooth and forget it, on the iOS part.